# php. Need idea how to distinct categories/subcategories/product/page=

Tags: php, mysql

Here are some examples of url

```
       0  |  1       |   2
----------------------------- 
.com / en / page=x   / product
.com / en / category / product
.com / en / category / page=x
.com / en / category / subcategory
```

Based on the word(-s) after particular `/` I decide what to fetch from mysql. For example if I see `product` I connect to `products` table and fetch one `product. If I see`subcategory`, I connect to`products`table and fetch all products where in`subcategory`column is name of`subcategory`.

I need decide, for example, what is after third trailing slash (product, page=x, or subcategory).

Now I at first remove last `/`

```
$url_slashes = rtrim( (ltrim($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],'/')) ,'/');
```

Then create array

```
$array_url_slashes = explode( "/", $url_slashes );
```

And then like this

```
if ( strpos( $array_url_slashes[2] ,'page=') !== false ) {
```

then it is `page` and so on.

This works if I limit maximum number of subcategories (or array elements).

But what would be solution for unlimited subcategories. I need not so much code, but need idea how all this works.

It would be simply for example `.com/en/c=category/s1=subcategory/s2=next-subcategory`

After searching google found this http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/
Appears, that there is a good idea.

For example url:

```
.com/en/electronics/portable-electronics/mp3-players/flash
```

And I need to fetch Title, Description, url for each element of url (for example, to create breadcrumbs)

All categories and subcategories are located in one mysql table

[image: mysql_table]

1) create variable from url `$url_slashes = rtrim( (ltrim($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],'/')) ,'/');`

2) create array `$array_url_slashes = explode( "/", $url_slashes );`

3) detect number of last element (last `/`) `$num_arr_trail_slash = count($array_url_slashes);`

4) mysql query like this

```
SELECT 
t1.name AS lev1, t2.name as lev2, t3.name as lev3, t4.name as lev4,
t1.url AS url1, t2.url as url2, t3.url as url3, t4.url as url4
FROM CategoryForTest AS t1
LEFT JOIN CategoryForTest AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.category_id
LEFT JOIN CategoryForTest AS t3 ON t3.parent = t2.category_id
LEFT JOIN CategoryForTest AS t4 ON t4.parent = t3.category_id
WHERE t4.name = ?;
```

`? is 'FLASH'` or `$array_url_slashes[$num_arr_trail_slash-1]`

And get such php array

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [lev1] => ELECTRONICS
        [lev2] => PORTABLE ELECTRONICS
        [lev3] => MP3 PLAYERS
        [lev4] => FLASH
        [url1] => url-electronics
        [url2] => url-portable-electronics
        [url3] => url-mp3-players
        [url4] => url-flash
    )

)
```

Comment: How about you just use htaccess for this? :)

Comment: Did not think about using htaccess. Do you mean to rewrite `s1=` (`s1=subcategory`) somehow? It would be good idea. Just need to get it to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an htaccess that rewrites your URL like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&lang=$2&action=$3 [L] 
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&lang=$2 [L] 
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

By rewriting your URL, it means you can always call the parameters as how you define them. In this example, I always go over index.php, next parameter is $page, next one is $lang and then I defined my $action.

So url example: www.yoururl.com/products/en/product.

So what can you do by using this htaccess, you can call the url variables like:

```
$_REQUEST['page']  == 'products'
$_REQUEST['lang']  == 'en'
$_REQUEST['action']  == 'product'
```

So based on the page name, you know what you have to show the user or what is comming, and based on action, you know what you are going to show / call.. .

You can just do it like:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['action']){
    switch($_REQUEST['action']{
        case 'product':
            //DO STUFF
            break;
    }
}
```

That's the basic idea.. Is this what you want?

Comment: Will try in reality (how it works). Trying to understand. The rewrite means that word/string after 3rd and next (4th,5th,etc.) `/` points to/means some action. I take word/string and ... Will check. At the moment can not understand:) Third word, for example, bookX. It may be category of bookX and it may be one product. From the word itself can not determine what it is. In `case 'product'` how can i decide that it is product?